# How to let the user connect to the database in Yii2?

Tags: php, database, yii2

I have an Yii application that works for a certain database structure. My company has such a database for almost every emplyee. So, I want the user to be able to connect to their own database when starting the app. This means that, in a form,  they will type in the username, password, the hostname and the name for their own database.I check the connection, and if it fails, it will show the user an error message, if it works, the rest of the app starts and the emplyee can access his personal data.

I do not have a list of all these databases and their credentials. Its only the emplyee who knows them.

I used this as reference [Yii2 Create Database Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254001/yii2-create-database-connection) . This is a problem often encoutered, but all the answers are about CActiveRecord and things no longer available in Yii2.

I have commented the `db` component in the `web.php` file and added it in the controller. The problem is, the models connect at bootstrap phase to a non existent `db` which raises an error at the moment of redirection to `index`.

How do I do to let the models know the connection changed in the `Yii::$app` configuration?

This is my action in the controller:

```
public function actionConnect() {
  $model = new DBcomponents();
  if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST))
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
    return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
{
      // Create Test DB Connection
      $form = $model;
      $dsn ='mysql:host='.$form->newhost.';dbname='.$form->dbname;
      $config = Yii::$app->getComponents();


      $db = new \yii\db\Connection([
              'dsn'      => $dsn,
              'username' => $form->username,
              'password' => $form->password,
              'charset'  => 'utf8'
              ]); 
      $db->open();
      try {
      // Check DB Connection
      if ($db->getIsActive()) {
        // Write Config
          $db->close();
          $config['components']['db'] =  $db;
          Yii::$app->setComponents($config['components']);
          Yii::$app->db->open();
          $success = TRUE;
          return $this->redirect(['index']);
      }else{
          $errorMsg = 'Incorrect Configurations';
      }
      } catch (Exception $e) {
          $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
      }
          } 
  else{
return $this->render('dbcreate', [
  'model' => $model,
]);}
 }
```

Comment: I found the way to do it. I will soon ppost an answer explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realised what I had to do.

I did  not write anything in the config file for the `db`. I set it, as you can see up here, in the controller. However, once I leave the controller, I lose this config. To keep it and be able to use it for the models, I saved this new connection in the cache. Then, as  qiang suggested here : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/5385-dynamic-db-connection/  I overrode the `getDbConnection()` static method, which in Yii2 is called `getDb()`. To do this, I created a `NewActiveRecord` class which extends `ActiveRecord`. Then I made all my methods extend this new class. Beware, if ever anything happens with the cache, the app fails.

Other than that, it works fine. Not perfect, as this way of doing it makes it take forever to load the pages of my app, because every single time the models do the connection. If anyone knows how to improve this, please do help. 
This is my new class.

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
class NewActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

public static function getDb() {
return Yii::$app->cache['dbconnect'];

}}
```