# How to connect to a database without the config file in Yii2?

Tags: database, yii2, connection

I am using, for the same problem, the code which is given in this question [Yii2 Create Database Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254001/yii2-create-database-connection/39327808#39327808).

I realise the `$config` variable is no longer the one in the web.php file, from the "config" folder, and that he is changing `$config`in his `Configuration::setConfig()` function.

My question for those more experienced than me in Yii is what should I write

- in the web.php file in the `db` field (or in the db.php file) to "create a database connection programmatically without using the config file" ?
- in the function `Configuration::setConfig()` to properly configure the application?

I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough. Please ask for details in the comments if needed. Thank you!

Comment: I should mention that if i have a valid initial database set in the db.php file and comment the Configuration::setConfig() line, it works well. It changes the initial database with the new one set in the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new connection this way

> ```
> $db = new yii\db\Connection([
>    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example',
>    'username' => 'root',
>    'password' => '',
>    'charset' => 'utf8',
> ]); and 
>
> $db->open();
> ```
>
> After the DB connection is established, one can execute SQL statements
>   like the following eg: :
>
> ```
>  $command = $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post');
>  $posts = $command->queryAll(); or 
>
>  $command = $connection->createCommand('UPDATE post SET status=1');
>  $command->execute();
> ```

you can look at this for doc and guide

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Am am setting my connection in the controller, as in the code references in my question. The problem is how not to connect to a db at bootstap phase. How to start the app with no connetion set in the config file?

Comment: You can start the application without any setting for db ..connection .. if you don't set any component for db ..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
So, step one, I start the app with no db component. I fill in the form , open in the controller a db connection and set it as component of the app. Then I redirect to my index page which has a Gridview of a model.  I get the error that there is no db component even though I had just set it in the controller. How should I avoid that?

Comment: You should set the connection when you need  when you leave the controller you don't have anymore the connection .. or you define the connection like a component at stratup or you should set the connection exacltly where you use it ..

Comment: That will require to change..you know, the whole app. Thank you, your answers have been very useful and solved my problem. I will do as you said and set the connection when I use it.

Comment: @mada   try thinking the fact of configure some db connection at startup and use these when you need .. (They do not consume many resources and are already ready when you need them)

Comment: right at start up, normally, I have no ideea what db my user will connect to ...it is the user who connects to the database and my app will use  that one.