# Multiproceccing + PyMongo lead to [Errno 111]

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, multiprocessing, pymongo

Good day!

I've just started playing around with `pymongo` and multiprocessing. I have received a multicore unit for my experiments, which runs `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, codename: bionic`. Just for the sake of experiment I have tried it both with `python 3.8` and `python 3.10`, unfortunately the results are similar:

```
>7lvv_E mol:na length:29  DNA (28-MER)
ELSE 7lvv_E
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "LoadDataOnSequence.py", line 54, in createCollectionPDB
    x = newCol.insert_one(dict2Write)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 698, in insert_one
    self._insert(document,
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 613, in _insert
    return self._insert_one(
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 602, in _insert_one
    self.__database.client._retryable_write(
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1497, in _retryable_write
    with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1829, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1816, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1766, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1802, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 496, in get_server_session
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 215, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60db2071e53de99692268c6f, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('127.0.0.1', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LoadDataOnSequence.py", line 82, in <module>
    myPool.map(createCollectionPDB, listFile("datum/pdb_seqres.txt"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60db2071e53de99692268c6f, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('127.0.0.1', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

I have been trying multiple times by modifying my code different ways, no luck though.
Also, I have tried both running code from PyCharm via SSH and by creating the local (at multicore machine) folder with all the necessary files.

I count the number of cores and create my `MongoClient`:

```
from multiprocessing import *
from pymongo import MongoClient



#Number of cores
x = cpu_count()
print(x)


myClient = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/')
```

I prepare a list to pass, using that function:

```
def listFile(fileName):
    fOpen = open(fileName)
    listFile = fOpen.readlines()
    arrOfArrs = []
    tmp1 = []
    for i in listFile:
        # print(i)
        if i.startswith(">"):
            if len(tmp1) > 1:
                arrOfArrs.append(tmp1)
            tmp1 = []
            tmp1.append(i.strip())
        else:
            tmp1.append(i.strip())
    #print(listFile)
    return arrOfArrs
```

That's the way I can prepare a big text file (in reality there's going to be even a larger one, I am just testing using one of the PDB files: https://www.wwpdb.org/ftp/pdb-ftp-sites I use the seqres file, I am not linking the exact file, as it will download immediately). And I suppose everything works till that moment.
Next is the function, which will be used in `Pool`:

```
def createCollectionPDB(fP):
        lineName = ""
        lineFASTA = ""
        colName = ""
        PDBName = ""
        chainIDName = ""
        typeOfMol = ""
        molLen = ""
        proteinName = ""
        for i in fP:
            print("test", i)
            print(lineName)
            if ">" in i:
                lineName = i.strip()
                print("LINE NAME")
                colName = lineName.split(" ")[0].strip()[1:]
                print("COLNAME", colName)
                PDBName = lineName.split("_")[0].strip()
                chainIDName = colName.split("_")[-1].strip()
                typeOfMol = lineName.split(" ")[1].strip().split(":")[1].strip()
                molLen = lineName.split(" ")[2].strip().split(":")[-1].strip()#[3].split(" ")[0].strip()
                proteinName = lineName.split(" ")[-1].strip()
                print(colName, PDBName, chainIDName, typeOfMol, molLen, proteinName)
            else:
                print("ELSE", colName)
                lineFASTA = i.strip()
                dict2Write={"PDB_ID" : PDBName, "Chain_ID" : chainIDName, "Molecule Type" : typeOfMol, "Length" : molLen, "Protein_Name" : proteinName, "FASTA" : lineFASTA}
                myNewDB = myClient["MyPrjPrj_PDBs"]
                newCol = myNewDB[colName]
                x = newCol.insert_one(dict2Write)
                print("PDB", x.inserted_id)#'''
```

That one used to work as well. Finally I `multiprocess`:

```
f1 = listFile("datum/pdb_seqres.txt")
myPool = Pool(processes=x)
myPool.map(createCollectionPDB, f1)
myPool.join()
myPool.close()
```

I have been looking through various solutions, like changing the Python version, trying different (5.0 and 4.x) versions of mongo, as well, as restarting mongo. I have also tried changing the number of processes, which leaves me with pretty much the same error, though stopping at a different line. Another option I've tried was using ssh_pymongo, with no luck as well.
Also it works without multiprocessing, though w/o multiprocessing I use it on a smaller file.

Comment: You need to create the client in each process. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68098987/forked-process-failure-during-socket-delivery-broken-pipe/68106492#68106492

Comment: @D.SM yeah thx I guess that helped, though there's still something fishy about the connection, as now it throws `autoreconnect`. In any case the problem that you have pointed is a real isssue in my code, as well, so if you put it as an answer I will gladly accept it

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the specific details of that particular exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process needs to have its own client, therefore you most likely need to create the client in each process instead of creating one prior to invoking multiprocessing.

[Forked process: Failure during socket delivery: Broken pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68098987/forked-process-failure-during-socket-delivery-broken-pipe/68106492#68106492) contains general information on how MongoDB drivers handle forking.